# Quickest Way To Create a Pre-Register Form

Tags: users

I'm looking to allow users to "Pre Register" for a new site (actually I'll use this for a standard 'template' process), I want to get users to sign up so I can keep them informed of news, updates etc on launch and want to get this function installed quickly. I'm not really want to 'hack' template.php at this stage (later maybe with ongoing development) so just need a really simple approach which will sign them up, subscribe to a newsletter and give registrants the normal 'subscribe/'unsubscribe' from within email contents. I have two roles, so can code the layout with simple "Sign Up" links going to relevant registration forms. In your opinion, what would be the best approach, maybe I should use a Rules structure (and tie in things like Coupon Codes/incentives) or would you suggest a different process?

PS:
Just like to add, that I use a process for pre-registration users to sign as up as such: 1st level - as a 'temp' role, then the user cannot go any further until they join one of either 2 roles (one free, one paid for services).

In following the accepted response below, I'll set the Notify up for a 'temp 'user then the user can choice on 'launch'  the Role route they wish to sign up for. Hope that helps readers. (-:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you suggest (using Rules for this) is far too complicated for me.

To do this with the minimum hassle, I would just set up a standard Drupal site and create a fixed front-page that says: "Pre-register for my great new site."   Configure permissions so that if the logged in user doesn't have admin permissions, all he/she is allowed to see is this fixed front page.

Then use [String Overrides](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) to replace the text "Create new account" in the login box with the text: "Click here to pre-register".  I.e. the by "pre-registering", the user really creates a standard account on the site.

Then auto-subscribe everyone that pre-registers to a newsletter (for a newsletter module you can, for example, use  [Notify](https://drupal.org/project/notify)). This will let you post updates on the site about the ongoing development, etc. that *also* are automatically sent to those who've pregistered as a digest newsletter e-mail.  (Notify let you auto-subscribe new users and also has a master switch to make subscribing and unsubscribing a breeze).

Later, when you've done setting up the site, you can ask the user to confirm his/her committment by ticking some field in the user profile, and silently convert those that confirm to regular users by given additional access permissions (and delete the rest).

Disclosure: I am the maintainer of Notify.

Comment: Thank you very much @gisle-hannemyr your suggestions are extremely helpful to my initial enquiry, and a great example of how drupal.stackexchange.com can help people quickly and promptly with answers to resolve issues irrespective of how the original question may sometimes seem too 'obvious' to pro-drupalists, but we all have to start somewhere and helpful pointers like this is the main reason I stay determined to use this SX for my number #1 port (-: Thanks a million (I'll check out your https://drupal.org/project/notify). Cheers.

Comment: Having had a think about the above, I'm now inclined to have a crack and hacking to create a custom register.tpl.php as using the core register form is creating issues with also a log-in option, (plus I'm using LoginTobogin later), so for this early 'launch' phase, need to streamline until fully operational. Still, Notify module seems a good function which I can use, I'll look to implement it for automatic newsletter subscriptions. Thanks again. (-: